# Excel subtract many columns from 1 column

Tags: microsoft-excel

i have tried to figure out how to subtract values from 1 column using other different column values to get final total value but can't seem to get it to work out. This what i have

> Column C2=(A1-B2,B3,B4,B5)

Column A1 has qty at hand and Columns B2,B3,B4,B5 are different locations were i want to distribute some of the quantities and the Column C2 should give me the total from the above scenario, any help on how to accomplish my problem would be highly appreciated. Thanx

Comment: `B2,B3,B4,B5` are all *cells* in *column* `B`. Please [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1347203/edit) you question with the correct terms

Comment: Yes, they are in the same column, kindly take note of that

Answer (score 0):

Subtract the SUM of the cells from the total:

```
=A1-SUM(B2:B5)
```